# change background-image value dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find all the elements with a specific background-image and change it to another one.
I tried doing it with this piexce of code:

```
jQuery('a').each( function() {
    if ( jQuery(this).css('background-image') == 'url("someurl.png")' ) {
        jQuery(this).css('background-image') == 'url("anotherurl.png")';
    }
});
```

but it didn't work...any idea how can i do it??
since this is a really small page i would rather go threw all elements in the page...
 there is a way to go threw all elements in page?

Comment: shouldn't be 'background-image', 'filename.png'?

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
jQuery(this).css('background-image') == 'url("anotherurl.png")';
```

to:

```
jQuery(this).css('background-image','url("anotherurl.png")');
```

[Setting a property with `.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2)

Answer (score 0):

When setting values with jQuery's `css()`, you'd do

```
jQuery(this).css('background-image', 'url("anotherurl.png"))';
```

It's a function, not a property that can be set with `=`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the setter of `css()` to change the property. You can also use `filter()` and the instance of jQuery passed in to the document ready handler to keep the `$` in use. Try this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('a').filter(function() {
        return $(this).css('background-image') == 'url("someurl.png")';
    }).css('background-image', 'url("anotherurl.png")');
});
```